# Drupal as a CAS Server

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, cas

I'm trying to set up a CAS system with our Drupal 6 site as the CAS Server. Note that I am not interested in setting up Drupal as a CAS client - all of the documentation I've been able to find to date as centered around that setup.

I've downloaded and installed the CAS module from http://drupal.org/project/cas. The module comes with a "cas server" that claims that it "Provides protocol compliant CAS Server", but I haven't been able to figure out how/if it works. There are no options that show up for the cas server; all of the options appear to be for the cas client.

After enabling the cas server, I attempted to visit the url of the cas system by going to [ourdomain]/cas, but drupal told me that "The requested page could not be found". I'm running out of ideas on how to get this working, and I'd appreciate help from the awesome stackoverflow community. You guys have never let me down!

Comment: I just discovered the README_SERVER.txt (duh! I've been staring at the screen to long). We have a valid https site thought, and visiting https://[our domain]/cas doesn't help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered that the CAS server **is** working, even though there is no page at https://[mydomain]/cas. This confuses me greatly though; how does phpCAS work, that it can use a url that doesn't exist? I'll vote your comment up if it makes sense!